# AutoCompleteExtender is not working for a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to use AutoCompleteExtender for autocomplete in TextBox. But not getting the results. I have used the following syntax :
In aspx page ::

```
<asp:scriptmanager EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtautocomplete" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" 
Enabled="true" EnableCaching="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
ServiceMethod="GetNames" ServicePath="~/Autocomplete.asmx"
TargetControlID="txtautocomplete" runat="server">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

and in Autocomplete.asmx   ::

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod()]
    public static string[] GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        ArrayList sampleList = new ArrayList();

        sampleList.Add("ABC"); sampleList.Add("Hello");

        sampleList.Add("Hi"); sampleList.Add("Apple");

        sampleList.Add("Hey");

        ArrayList filteredList = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string s in sampleList)
        {
            if (s.ToLower().StartsWith(prefixText.ToLower()))

                filteredList.Add(s);
        }
        return (string[])filteredList.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

When I am running the Autocomplete.asmx directly then on clicking Invoke button I am getting the right results. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried configuring the endpoint in your web.config like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="http://rrdb.dev"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <services>
    <service name="Service">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628467.aspx